# Why j is initialized to 0 instead of its incremented value in the loop?

Tags: c

Consider the following c code:

```
int main()
{
    int a[5] = {5, 2, 1, 6, 3}, b[5] = {1, 6, 3, 2, 5}, c[10], i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        while (a[i] != b[j])
            j++;
        c[k]   = a[i];
        c[k+1] = b[j];
        k      = k + 2;
    }
    for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i += 2)
        printf("%d->%d\n", c[i], c[i + 1]);
    getch();
}
```

The program prints two same numbers each choosen from a[5] and b[5]

Q: j is initialized only once and in the loop the value of j gets incremented, so it may get incremented beyond 5 as no again initialization of j takes place inside the loop, hence the o/p should be some garbage value, but it is not? Why?

Comment: Indent your code properly, use a sane coding style and meaningful variable names. Then the answer shall be revealed.

Comment: Yes, `j` is incremented beyond 5 walking through some garbage. By a happy coincidence it probably walks until it points to the array `a` and finds all necessary values there.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily point to `a` .  It is just wandering its way through random memory until it finds a `2`, then it goes on until it finds a `1`.  Odds are pretty good it will find them somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the *address* of the array elements whose *values* match, you can see the truth of @Marian's comment, that `j` indexes the same array as `i` does, after the first match.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {5, 2, 1, 6, 3}, b[5] = {1, 6, 3, 2, 5}, c[10], i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        while (a[i] != b[j])
            j++;
        printf ("%p %p\n", (void*)&a[i], (void*)&b[j]);   // added a cue
        c[k]   = a[i];
        c[k+1] = b[j];
        k      = k + 2;
    }
    for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i += 2)
        printf("%d->%d\n", c[i], c[i + 1]);
    getch();
}
```

Program output

```
0018FF2C 0018FF24
0018FF30 0018FF30
0018FF34 0018FF34
0018FF38 0018FF38
0018FF3C 0018FF3C
5->5
2->2
1->1
6->6
3->3
```

Comment: [`%p` requires an argument of type `void*`](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/24867814/printfp-and-casting-to-void). So cast `&a[i]` and `&b[j]` to `void*`

Answer (score 2):

`j` contains 0 when entering the first `for` loop. It becomes 4 when exiting the `while` loop as only then will the condition `a[i] != b[j]` be false.

Then, in the next iteration of the first `for` loop, `j` gets incremented and you try to read past the array (`b[5]`,`b[6]` etc) and this invokes [Undefined Behavior](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which means that anything can happen.

The reason that it worked perfectly is by pure luck. But you cannot rely on this.