# Formatting code to access array index of type struct

Tags: c, pointers

I have a below code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    typedef struct sample { 
        int num;        
    } abc;

    typedef struct exmp{        
        abc *n1;        
    } ccc;

    abc *foo;
    foo = (abc*)malloc(sizeof(foo));
    ccc tmp;
    tmp.n1 = foo;

    ccc stack[10];

    stack[0] = tmp;
    printf("address of tmp is %p\n",&tmp);
    // need to print address contained in stack[0]

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I want to check if the address at `stack[0]` is same as address of tmp. How do I print address at `stack[0]` as I printed out tmp's address?

Comment: 1) `foo=(abc*)malloc(sizeof(foo));` --> `foo=(abc*)malloc(sizeof(*foo));` 2) `tmp.n` --> `tmp.n1`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , The cast `(abc*)` should be removed as this is C, not C++.

Comment: Why does that matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very simple, just do this

```
printf("address of tmp is %p and address of stack[0] %p\n",
    (void *)&tmp, (void *)&stack[0]);
```

and actually this will work

```
printf("address of tmp is %p and address of stack[0] %p\n", 
    (void *)&tmp, (void *)stack);
```

Also, [Do not cast `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), and always check that the returned value is not `NULL`, i.e. that it's a valid pointer.

Comment: &stack[0] gives the address of stack[0] itself , is it the same as address stored at stack[0]?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you explain more?

Comment: Suppose , int var; int stack[4]; stack[0]=var .I meant does &stack[0] gives the address of stack[0] or address of var? In the above question I am expecting stack[0] to have address of tmp( var ).

Comment: in `stack[0] = var` the value is copied, so `&stack[0]` will always give the address if `stack[0]`. In fact you can't change the address of an array, at least I don't know of any way to do it.

Comment: [`%p` requires an argument of type `void*`](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/24867814/printfp-and-casting-to-void) . So cast the arguments of `printf` to `void*`

Comment: @CoolGuy to make it complain on `gcc` I needed `-pedantic` but since it did complain I am going to change it.