# The "%p" printf parameter

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){
       printf("%p");
}
```

This is the output:
`0x7ffdd9b973d8`

I know `%p` stands for pointer and when using it as for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){
 int i = 0;
 printf("%p", i);
}
```

it returns the pointer address of `i`. But my question is what does it return when not adding any other argument in the printf function just `printf("%p")`

Comment: `printf("%p", i);` does not print address of `i`. You'd need `printf("%p", (void *) &i);` for that.

Comment: I think it's just a random address in memory. Well, not random as in generated, but not predictable directly.  Basically garbage.

Comment: @ant do you need the `(void *)`, though?

Comment: In the first case, the compiler should have warned you the code is incorrect (missing argument). In the second case you are not printing *the pointer address of `i`*. You are printing `i` is if it were a pointer, but it isn't and again the compiler should have warned you. Why are you asking what the compiler has already told you? Your question is equivalent to asking how much milk the milkman will deliver, when you have not told him.

Comment: @cullub: Pedantically, yes. A `void *` pointer is expected by `printf`. A `[signed/unsigned] char *` pointer can be used without a cast, since it is guaranteed to have the same representation as `void *`. But `int *` can have a different representation, which is why it has to be cast to `void *`.

Comment: @cullub [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867814/printfp-and-casting-to-void). Pointers may have different object representations.

Comment: So, to sum this up it is the data stored previously in the register? Trash data from another process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trash. `printf` uses a variable-length argument list. It uses the format string to determine how many arguments you actually passed. If you did not actually pass anything in, it will still read from basically arbitrary  portions of memory as though you did. The result is undefined/trash.

Some compilers will be able to catch this situation with a warning because the `printf` family of functions is so popular. Some cases may crash your system if the function tries to read from memory you do not have access to. There is no way to tell how it will behave next time even if you have obtained a certain result.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of

```
printf("%p");
```

is undefined. When you specify a `%p` format in the format string, the corresponding argument of `void *` (or `char *`) type shall be present in the argument list.

Comment: I think OP is asking for how that rule is enforced, if at all.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: I don't see it. The question appears to be about the printed garbage and where it comes from.

Comment: That makes sense, but your answer does not really answer where the garbage comes from. What does undefined mean in this context? OP is getting a concrete result after all.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: A practical experiment always produces a result that is *concrete* in some sense. I don't quote the standard definition of "undefined behavior" since everybody is probably sick and tired of hearing it  in the umpteenth time.

Comment: @MadPhysicist see [what is undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/1505939).  I'm thinking of getting a macro keyboard for the amount of times I link that link

Answer (score 4):

> But my question is what does it return when not adding any other argument in the printf function just printf("%p");

Anything. Nothing. Random junk. Maybe it crashes.

There is no way to know without investigating a specific combination of compiler, CPU, platform, libraries, execution environment, and so on. There is no rule that requires it to operate any particular way.