# __attribute(aligned) test. What does it do?

Tags: c

I am using a couple of online compilers to test a sample program (for reference, the one in ideone and the one in tutorialspoint) 
The program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> 

uint8_t Array[5]__attribute((aligned(32)));
uint8_t Array2[5]__attribute((aligned(8)));
static uint8_t Array3[5]__attribute((aligned(8)));
static uint8_t Array4[5]__attribute((section("bbs"),aligned(32)));


int main()
{
    printf("%p %p %p %p %p \n", &Array[0], &Array[1], &Array[2], &Array[3],&Array[4]);
    printf("%p %p %p %p %p \n", &Array2[0], &Array2[1], &Array2[2], &Array2[3],&Array2[4]);
    printf("%p %p %p %p %p \n", &Array3[0], &Array3[1], &Array3[2], &Array3[3],&Array3[4]);
    printf("%p %p %p %p %p \n", &Array4[0], &Array4[1], &Array4[2], &Array4[3],&Array4[4]);

    return 0;
}
```

The results are for example

```
0x2aff9175b0a0 0x2aff9175b0a1 0x2aff9175b0a2 0x2aff9175b0a3 0x2aff9175b0a4 
0x2aff9175b080 0x2aff9175b081 0x2aff9175b082 0x2aff9175b083 0x2aff9175b084 
0x2aff9175b068 0x2aff9175b069 0x2aff9175b06a 0x2aff9175b06b 0x2aff9175b06c 
0x2aff9175b040 0x2aff9175b041 0x2aff9175b042 0x2aff9175b043 0x2aff9175b044
```

I can see that aligned does not seem to have an effect on where the array elements are stored. What does aligned actually do? (I am asking *after* reading the explanation in [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) which I didn't quite catch.)

Comment: Nitpick: You must cast the arguments to `void *`.

Comment: Arrays are *always* stored contiguously. You can only influence the alignment of the array's start address with this attribute. Eg `Array` will *start* at an address divisable by 32.

Comment: I see. Why would that be important? And how can I see that in the example results I posted above?

Comment: Try to divide the first address printed by 32. For why this *could* be important: e.g. interfacing with DMA hardware requiring that, or some performance consideration -- this is a quite broad question.

Comment: It's an extension anyways and writing *application* code, you'll probably never need it.

Comment: The same thing as _Alignof.

Answer (score 4):

The alignment attribute is described [here in the GNU Compiler documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html).

It said about it:

> This attribute specifies a minimum alignment for the variable or structure field, measured in bytes.

That means you will set the minimum alignment but for the **beginning of the array**. The rest of the array is guaranteed to be contiguous, that means the addresses that follows are dependent on the type in your example `uint8_t`. If the array start address is at `0x2aff9175b0a0` like in your case the next address must be 1 byte after it at `0x2aff9175b0a1` (`0xa0 --> 0xa1`).

To explain your example:

```
Alignment 32 beginning at: 0x2aff9175b0a0 --> 0xa0 = 160 = 32 * 5
Alignment 8  beginning at: 0x2aff9175b080 --> 0x80 = 128 = 8  * 16
Alignment 8  beginning at: 0x2aff9175b068 --> 0x68 = 104 = 8  * 13
Alignment 32 beginning at: 0x2aff9175b040 --> 0x40 = 64  = 32 * 2
```

As you see the alignment of the beginning of the array is as you want it. You could increase the alignment and watch the addresses again. But also consider:

> Note that the effectiveness of aligned attributes may be limited by inherent limitations in your linker. On many systems, the linker is only able to arrange for variables to be aligned up to a certain maximum alignment.

Further if you use `printf()` to print the addresses with `%p`, then also cast the addresses to a `void*`, because the pointer types doesn't need to have the same representations except for some of them. That fact is also [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24867946/8051589).

Comment: This actually seems to reference the material the OP said he didn't understand.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You're right, I didn't saw his link... But I added a little calculation example that explains his results.

Comment: @KansaiRobot: Does this answer helped you or is here no answer that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You might get a better picture of what's going on with slightly different sample code.  Here's an adaptation of your program.  There's no virtue in printing the addresses of elements indexed by `[1]` etc; those positions are 100% controlled by the type (`uint8_t`) and the start address of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> 

uint8_t Array1[5]__attribute((aligned(32)));
uint8_t Array2[5]__attribute((aligned(8)));
static uint8_t Array3[5]__attribute((aligned(8)));
static uint8_t Array4[5]__attribute((aligned(32)));

uint16_t u16_a1[3];
uint16_t u16_a2[3];
uint16_t u16_a3[3];

uint16_t u16_a4[3] __attribute((aligned(32)));
uint16_t u16_a5[3] __attribute((aligned(32)));
uint16_t u16_a6[3] __attribute((aligned(32)));

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s: %p\n", "Array1", (void *)Array1);
    printf("%s: %p\n", "Array2", (void *)Array2);
    printf("%s: %p\n", "Array3", (void *)Array3);
    printf("%s: %p\n", "Array4", (void *)Array4);

    printf("%s: %p\n", "u16_a1", (void *)u16_a1);
    printf("%s: %p\n", "u16_a2", (void *)u16_a2);
    printf("%s: %p\n", "u16_a3", (void *)u16_a3);
    printf("%s: %p\n", "u16_a4", (void *)u16_a4);
    printf("%s: %p\n", "u16_a5", (void *)u16_a5);
    printf("%s: %p\n", "u16_a6", (void *)u16_a6);

    return 0;
}
```

I had to remove the `section(bbs),` directive; the Mac linker didn't accept it.  I also renamed `Array` to `Array1` for self-consistency with the rest of the array names.

The output I got was:

```
Array1: 0x10a1fc040
Array2: 0x10a1fc048
Array3: 0x10a1fc028
Array4: 0x10a1fc020
u16_a1: 0x10a1fc04e
u16_a2: 0x10a1fc054
u16_a3: 0x10a1fc05a
u16_a4: 0x10a1fc060
u16_a5: 0x10a1fc080
u16_a6: 0x10a1fc0a0
```

Note that the address of `Array1` is aligned on a 32-byte boundary, and `Array2` is on an 8 byte boundary just after `Array1`.  Similarly, `Array3` and `Array4` are located on appropriately aligned boundaries.  (Of course, a 32-byte boundary is an address which ends `z0` in hex, where `z` is an even number.  An 8-byte boundary is an address that ends in `8` or `0` in hex.)

The `u16_a1` to `u16_a3` arrays are not alignment constrained.  They're 6 bytes each, and the three addresses differ by 6 bytes.

By contrast, the `u16_a4` to `u16_a6` arrays are constrained to a 32-byte boundary.  As you can see, their addresses differ from each other by 32 bytes, and each is located on a 32-bit boundary, whereas if they were unconstrained, they'd be much closer together.  You might note that `u16_a3` and `u16_a4` happen to be contiguous in memory — pure chance, not planning on my part.

You can adapt this code to play with other types and alignments.