Stack Memory Layout
I understand stack moves from Higher memory address to Lower memory address,To find the size of the structure without using any library calls i used below logic,
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node{
    int a;
    char b;
    int c;
} Node;

int main(){
    Node obj1;
    Node obj2;
    printf("Size of struct is %ld\n",(char*)&obj1 - (char*)&obj2);
    return 0;
}


The result is -12, what makes the result -ve.
I tried disabling the compiler optimizations as well.
The expectation is the difference between the obj1 and obj will be +ve since obj1 will be first allocated in stack with a higher address and then followed by obj2.

You can't assume variables will be allocated in the order they're declared.

You cannot subtract (well, it's Undefined Behaviour) 2 pointers unless they point somewhere within the same object or 1 element past the end. Your program could outpit anything: it could output what you expect, it could output "syntax error", it could just simply open the CD tray, etc, ... (it could even give different results based on the phase of the moon)

See C11 6.5.6p9.

You could subtract pointers to elements of the same structure array. The value can be different from what you get with sizeof, and the size of a structure can be more than the sum of all elements' sizes. There might be padding between the structure elements or after the last element.

I wrote a detailed answer to a slightly different version of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46038253 Please read it and then tell us if there's anything you still don't understand.

@Bodo More importantly for this question, comparing the addresses of two elements of the same array cannot reveal anything about the direction of stack growth.

"I understand stack moves from Higher memory address to Lower memory address" -- that's machine specific.  C has nothing whatever to say about the arrangement of the stack, or whether there even is one.  Historically, there have been machines with a stack that grew from low addresses toward high ones.

The result of a pointer difference has type ptrdiff_t.  It is not safe to assume that this type is the same as long int, which your printf format does.

You can't compare/subtract pointers to different objects. But you can convert the pointers to uintptr_t and then subtract those.

There's no guarantee that the result will be meaningful, but in most extant architectures it will probably produce the result you want.

You said: "To find the size of the structure without using any library calls". in C, sizeof is computed at compile time, not runtime. There are no "library calls" involved in x = sizeof(Node). The compiler figures it out and replaces the expression with a constant. sizeof is an operator, not a function.


The expectation is the difference between the obj1 and obj will be +ve since obj1 will be first allocated in stack with a higher address and then followed by obj2.

The C language provides no basis whatsoever for such an expectation:

The difference between two pointers is defined only for pointers into or just past the end of the same array (C23 6.5.7/10).  Your program attempts to compute the difference between pointers that do not have such a relationship, so anything could happen.

Even if we assumed, with no basis in the language spec, that pointer differences were computed in a flat global address space, C says nothing about where automatic variables are allocated, neither in absolute terms nor in relative ones, so you would still have no basis for any expectation about the result of the pointer difference.  In particular, C does not assume the use of a stack, and it certainly says nothing about the direction in which such a stack might grow.

Even if we additionally assumed, with no basis in the language spec, that the machine uses a call stack to manage storage for automatic objects, AND that that stack grows downward, C still does not guarantee that automatic objects are allocated so that the addresses of consecutively declared objects track the direction of stack growth.  That might be a more reasonable assumption in an interpreted language, where we might suppose that space is allocated in the order that control reaches variable declarations, but C is not (generally) such a language.


So, why do you get a result of the form you do? Details of your C implementation, and possibly circumstances of your particular run of the program.  It is rarely useful to analyze undefined behavior.
