# Output using char * to point to int array

Tags: c, pointers, endianness

What is the output of following program written in C?

Is it `2 0` or `0 2`, and why?

```
int main()
{
    int arr[]={2,3,4};  // predefined pointer
    char *p;
    p=(char *)arr;

    printf("%d\n",*p);
    printf("%p\n",p);
    p=p+1;

    printf("%d\n",*p);
    printf("%p\n",p);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Where is this code from? it looks like an interview or test question. Did you test the program and now you can't explain the output to yourself?

Comment: What is the output on your machine? The real question would be `2 0` or `0 0`. Why should it ever print `0 2`?

Comment: Why can't you execute it and see for yourself? Don't you understand the result you are getting, or what?

Comment: @Lundin, that's not good advice for undefined or implementation-defined behaviour such as this.  The results aren't specified by the language and depend on the size and layout of `char` and `int`.

Comment: @Gerhadh, `0 2` is a likely result on MC6800 platforms (possibly also on VAX; my memory is slightly hazy there).

Comment: @Gerhardh Why is 68000 relevant?  I know that's 32-bit.  I mentioned 6800, where `int` is usually 16 bits and `char` 8.

Comment: @Gerhardh: 68000 is a 16 bit CPU and typically C on that arch used 16 bit `int`. Only 68020 and higher used 32 bit `int`  on some platforms (typically Unix systems).

Comment: @TobySpeight sorry, I messed up the CPUs.

Answer (score 6):

The result depends on the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your system as well as the size of an `int` (it also depends on the number of bits in a byte, but for now we'll assume it's 8).

Endianness dictates the ordering of bytes in types such as integers.  x86 based processors are **little-endian**, meaning that the least significant byte is first, while others are **big-endian** meaning the most significant byte is first.

For example, for a variable of type `int` with the value 2, and assuming an `int` is 32 bit, the memory on a big-endian system looks like this:

```
-----------------
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
-----------------
```

While on a little-endian system it looks like this:

```
-----------------
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
-----------------
```

Moving on to what happens when you take a `char *` and point it to an int (or a member of an `int` array).  Normally, using a pointer to one type to point to another type and read the value though the other pointer is a strict aliasing violation which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), however the C standard has an exception for character types to allow you to access the bytes in an object's representation.  So in this case it's allowed.

When you do this:

```
p=(char *)arr;
```

It causes `p` to point to the first byte of the first member of the array `arr`.

On big endian systems:

```
-----
| . | p
-----
  |
  v
-------------------------------------------------
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | arr
-------------------------------------------------
|    arr[0]     |    arr[1]     |    arr[2]     |
-------------------------------------------------
```

On little endian:

```
-----
| . | p
-----
  |
  v
-------------------------------------------------
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | arr
-------------------------------------------------
|    arr[0]     |    arr[1]     |    arr[2]     |
-------------------------------------------------
```

So when you read the value of `*p` you'll get 0 on big endian systems and 2 on little endian systems.

When you then perform `p=p+1`, you increase the address `p` points to by 1 *character*, i.e. 1 byte, so now it looks like this:

Big endian:

```
-----
| . | p
-----
  |----
      v
-------------------------------------------------
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | arr
-------------------------------------------------
|    arr[0]     |    arr[1]     |    arr[2]     |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Little endian:

```
-----
| . | p
-----
  |----
      v
-------------------------------------------------
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | arr
-------------------------------------------------
|    arr[0]     |    arr[1]     |    arr[2]     |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Now `*p` contains the value 0 on both big endian and little endian systems.  This assumes however that an `int` is 32-bit.  If an `int` is 16 bit, it instead looks like this:

Big endian:

```
-----
| . | p
-----
  |----
      v
-------------------------
| 0 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 4 | arr
-------------------------
|arr[0] |arr[1] |arr[2] |
-------------------------
```

Little endian:

```
-----
| . | p
-----
  |----
      v
-------------------------
| 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 4 | 0 | arr
-------------------------
|arr[0] |arr[1] |arr[2] |
-------------------------
```

In this case `*p` is 2 on big endian systems and 0 on little endian systems after incrementing.

Comment: Technically, the answer also depends on `CHAR_BIT` - easily forgotten if you only work with small-char systems...  For example, with `char` and `int` both 16 bits wide, `2 3` is another possible result.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
int arr[]={2,3,4};
```

looks like below if your system supports little endian, in case of big endian output may vary.

```
 arr[2]      arr[1]   |------------arr[0]-----------------------------|  
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     4      |   3    | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0010  | 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
           0x108    0x104       0x103      0x102       0x101       0x100 -- assume arr base address starts from 0x100
                                                                     arr
MSB                                                                  LSB
```

Now when you do

```
char *p;
p=(char *)arr;
```

Here `p` is a *char pointer* & `arr` type casted as `char*` which means pointer `p` points to *one byte memory location at a time* i.e first time `0x100` to `0x101`.

When the statement

```
printf("%d\n",*p);
```

executes it prints what data is there in `0x100-0x101` location which is `2`, hence it prints `2`.

And next when you do

```
p=p+1;
```

the pointer `p` increments by one byte i.e now `p` points to `0x101` memory location and when the statement `printf("%d\n",*p);` executes it prints what data is there in `0x101-0x102` location which is `0`, hence it prints `0`.

Also while using `%p` you should typecast pointer variable as `void*` as [printf("%p") and casting to (void *)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867814/printfp-and-casting-to-void)

```
printf("%p\n",(void*)p);
```