# ` int a = 2; int b = a;` report unexpected error

Tags: c

Suppose such a snippet of minimal code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = a;
    printf("a = %d, &a = %d", a, &a);
    printf("b = %d, &b = %d", b, &b);

    return 0;
}
```

I ran it and get error report as:

```
test.c:6:31: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
        printf("a = %d, &a = %d", a, &a);
                             ~~      ^~
test.c:7:31: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
        printf("b = %d, &b = %d", b, &b);
                             ~~      ^~
2 warnings generated.
```

I assume `a = 2` `b = 2` is equivalent to `a = b = 2`, nonetheless the complier remind info hardly to understand.

Comment: To print a pointer, use `%p` instead of `%d`. `&a` is not an `int`, but a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: Your title is misleading. As you see by the compile output, these are warnings and produced by another line.

Comment: `&a` is pointer to int, hence while printing it use `%p` and typecast as `void*` as [p conversion specifier requires an argument of type void *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867814/printfp-and-casting-to-void)

Comment: The compiler helpfully underlines the line that has an error, and spells out its reason in plain English.

Comment: I have to say that as compiler messages go, that one is particularly helpful and easy to read.

Comment: Why &a is a pointer? a is allocated a chuck of memory with value 2 stored. &a is the address of the memory, I guess I did not utilize pointer within the code. @Achal

Comment: `&a` is of type pointer to `int` because `a` is of type `int`. Often, when we talk about pointers, we are discussing actual variables, but sometimes we are just talking about temporary values -- things created by the compiler as an intermediate value in a larger calculation, or to pass to a function as a parameter (as in this case), or to return from a function. This is getting beyond the scope of the initial question, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to print a pointer using the `%d` format specifier, which is used to print an `int`.  That's why you get the warning.

To print a pointer, use the `%p` format specifier:

```
printf("a = %d, &a = %p", a, (void*)&a);
printf("b = %d, &b = %p", b, (void*)&b);
```

Also, be sure to cast the pointer to `void *`.  The reason for this is because not all pointer types necessarily have the same representation, and a variadic function can't properly do a conversion because it doesn't know what the actual type is.  So an explicit cast to `void *` is needed.

Comment: Could you elaborate why the cast to `void*` is recommendable?

Comment: I assume &a is the address of value 2 rather than a pointer.

Comment: @riderdragon There is no such thing as the address of value `2`.

Comment: @Scheff `%p` expects `void *` and passing another type would invoke undefined behaviour. In C different pointer types also can have different representations.

Comment: @riderdragon `&a` is the address of `a`, which had a value of 2 last time you looked at it

Comment: Why &a is a pointer? a is allocated a chuck of memory with value 2 stored. &a is the address of the memory, I guess I did not utilize pointer within the code.  @Osiris

Comment: The complier and answers mentioned pointer, but there are no pointer in the codes with my limited knowledge. @TimRandall

Comment: @Osiris I just inspected [`Default argument promotions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Pointer_conversions). It doesn't mention anything about pointers. So, I believe this is the reason for explicit cast to `void*` is recommendable.

Comment: `&a` is an _expression_ whose _value_ is the address of `a` and whose _type_ is pointer-to-int.

Comment: @riderdragon What do you think is returned by the address operator `&`? [Address of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Address_of): _The address-of operator produces the non-lvalue address of its operand, suitable for initializing a pointer to the type of the operand._

Comment: so &a has it own address of &&a, rephrase it if I want to know the address of a, there should be another memory space to be allocated  to store the address? @TimRandall

Comment: ty, I am reading more to understand it @Scheff

Comment: @riderdragon `a` is a local variable. `&a` is the address operator applied to `a` providing the address of `a` (type pointer to type of `a`). E.g. `int a;` `&a` will provide a value of type `int*` (with address of `a`). You may store this value (pointer) in another variable: `int a; int *pA = &a;` Now, in turn you can get the address of `pA`. BUT: you cannot get the address of `&a`. The returned value is non-lvalue i.e. nothing with necessary storage which might be addressed. Please, distinguish "address of something" and "something which has an address". `&a` is the former but not the latter.

Comment: I appreciate it deeply for your patient tutorial. @Scheff