# Memory address inside a function

Tags: c++, c

### MAIN

```
tst_struct *tst1;
printf("P outside function1: %p \n", tst1); //Output: 0x0
tst_func(tst1);
```

### Function

```
tst_struct *tst_func(tst_struct *tst1)
{
    printf("P from param: %p \n",tst1);  // Output 0x0
    tst_struct *tst2;
    printf("P inside function: %p \n", tst2); // Output 0x7ffeebcf8940
}
```

I dont understand why that happened.

I did the same thing in both functions.

If i create a variable and check for address on main, without assign any value, result is 0x0.

But if i create any variable inside another function, i receive an addresss.

There is some difference between main and "normal" functions?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to *Undefined Behavior* - `tst_struct *tst1;` declares an *uninitialized* pointer - it's value is indeterminate. Same for `tst_struct *tst2;`. The address held be each pointer is simply garbage until assigned a valid memory address. Answer the question "What address does `tst1` hold before I attempt to print that value?" If your answer is "I don't know..." don't print it `:)`

Comment: Using the values of uninitialized variables is undefined behavior. Don't try to make sense of it.

Comment: Just always initialize your variables and don't worry about it :)

Comment: But in that case, i want to start to build a list. So for me, is necessary to start with a empty value to make a if statement like (!tst); So to do that, you guys recommend to simple after create, set tst = NULL? Cause if i try to access that, will get seg fault

Comment: on that specific projects i have a limit of 25 lines per function, so dont want to waste to much lines

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin But uninitialized variables takes unspecified values and usage of such unspecified values results in unspecified behavior, not undefined. The behavior is undefined since we have to cast `tst_struct *` to `void *` explicitly in order to use with `%p` in place of the ellipsis.

Comment: Well granted, we can word-smith that down to the exact language of the standard, but the result is the same whether unspecified or undefined -- the train has already fallen off the tracks. Have you made that same comment in response to R Sahu?

Comment: @RSahu Uninitialized variables take unspecified values. Usage of unspecified values is unspecified behavior, not undefined. `N1570, 3.4.4. Unspecified behavior`: _use of an unspecified value_

Answer (score 2):

Undefined behaviour. If the value is zero, you're lucky. You've got an uninitialised variable, and are wondering why it has a random value? You may get zero in main, or in a debug build *(which tends to init memory to zero)*, or you may not. It depends on the compiler/os/cpu, and it should never be taken for granted. It could be anything, because it's undefined.

Comment: Getting UB that looks like what you want is the opposite of lucky - it's the hardest bug to find.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behaviours here.

First, I’ll just assume that you’ve included `<stdio.h>`.

`tst1` is uninitialised. If you try to print the value, one of the possibilities is that you get `0x0`. But, anything else can happen. Same thing with `tst2`.

Another thing, when you use `%p` format specifier in `printf()`, to be strictly conforming, you need to supply a `void *`. Therefore, strictly speaking, you should use, for example:

```
printf("P outside function1: %p \n", (void *)tst1);
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24867850/10616174