# proving pointers address in c

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, string-literals

Trying to understand pointer.

Below, I just want to prove to myself the below

address of str ( &str)  = address of where str2 is pointed to(str2)
actual memory of address for str2 is something different(&str2)

However, when I compile below I get seg fault saying "morePointers.c:6:56: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat]"

How can I correct this while proving this in the code?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char str = "goodbye";
    char *str2 = str;

    printf("%d %d %s %d %d\n", &str2, str2, str2, str, &str);
}
```

Comment: Use `%p`  to print pointers. And if you really want some *proof* consider using https://frama-c.com/

Comment: Is this you _actual_ code? Don't you have `#include`s? Yes, they matter.

Comment: `char str = "goodbye"` Is this a typo? must be `char *str` or `char str[]`

Comment: Save time. "when I compile" certainly lacked enabling all warnings.  Turn them all on, faster feedback the stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this declaration

```
char str = "goodbye";
```

you are trying to initialize an object of the type `char` with a string literal that in the initialization expression has the type `char *`.

You have to write

```
char *str = "goodbye";
```

Instead of this declaration

```
char *str2 = str;
```

it seems you mean

```
char **str2 = &str;
```

that is you are creating a pointer that points to the pointer `str`.

Thus dereferencing the pointer `str2` you will get the value stored in the pointer `str` that is the address of the first character of the string literal `"goodbye"`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *str = "goodbye";
    char **str2 = &str;

    printf( "str = %p is the same as *str2 = %p\n", ( void * )str, ( void * )*str2 );
    printf( "str2 = %p contains the address of str (&str) = %p\n", ( void *)str2, ( void *)&str );

    printf( "The string literal pointed to by str = %s\n"
            "is the same as pointed to by *str2 = %s\n",
            str, *str2 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
str = 0x561655562008 is the same as *str2 = 0x561655562008
str2 = 0x7ffdb7fc57a8 contains the address of str (&str) = 0x7ffdb7fc57a8
The string literal pointed to by str = goodbye
is the same as pointed to by *str2 = goodbye
```

Pay attention to that using the conversion specifier `%d` with pointers results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I am going over this.. btw, what is %p ? where can I look up documentation on this?

Comment: @user3502374 It is a conversion specifier designated to output pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the correct code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char *str = "goodbye";  // a '*' was missing in your code
  char* str2 = str;

  // you need to use %p for pointer values
  // and for each argument for a %p you need to cast to (void*)

  printf("%p %p %s %p %p\n", (void*)&str2, (void*)str2, str2, (void*)str, (void*)&str);
}
```

Typical possible output for this code on a 32 bit system

```
00FFF710 00996B30 goodbye 00996B30 00FFF71C
```

Typical possible output for this code on a 64 bit system

```
0x7ffc8f58ada0 0x555ba93f6004 goodbye 0x555ba93f6004 0x7ffc8f58ad98
```

Comment: "*for each argument for a `%p` you need to cast to `(void*)`*" - Why? `printf("%p %p %s %p %p\n", &str2, str2, str2, str, &str);` works too with `-Wall` and `-Werror` flag enabled.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Because `%p` expects a `void *` argument and anything else is undefined behavior (C11 7.1.4): *"If an argument to a function has [...] a type (after promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined."* and (C11 7.21.6.1 *The `fprintf` function*): *"`p` The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner."*

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio usually it works without the `(void*)` cast, but the standard says it needs to be `void*`, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24867850/898348. But to be honest I don't really understand _why_ passing a pointer without the cast could cause UB.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Some systems might have "fat pointers" of different sizes that contain information about the type. None that I know of have this, but it's possible.

Comment: @S.S.Anne good point

Comment: I downvoted because there's many easily-accessible duplicates and if not then this qualifies as a typo. Posting answers to low-quality questions like this to get reputation (which works) is low. Feel free to revenge-downvote me if you wish but it's my choice.

Comment: @S.S.Anne that's OK

Comment: @S.S.Anne So I need to do this also when printing the address of a non-pointer variable, like `int i = 25; printf("%p",(void*)&i);`

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yeah. I hope the C committee changes that in C20.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio yes, but `&i` _is_ a pointer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, but I meant not a "*real*" lvalue pointer variable.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Would be definitely worth an update.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Redirecting to [`printf("%p")` and casting to `(void *)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867814/printfp-and-casting-to-void)...