# Why is it pointing to the same address?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
int x = 5;
int* p = &x;
*p = 6;
int** q = &p;
int *** r= &q;
printf("%d\n",*p); //dereferencing p
printf("%d\n",*q); //getting address of q
printf("%d\n",**q); //dereferencing q
printf("%d\n",**r); //getting address of r
printf("%d\n",***r); //dereferencing r
}
```

Variable q has the memory address of p while variable r has the memory address of q, then why does when trying to print the memory address of q and r same results are getting produced?

Comment: Nowhere here do you print the memory address of `r` (that would be `printf("%p\n", r);`). Also, the correct format specifier for pointers is `%p`, `%d` might even truncate the address.

Comment: What do you mean by "memory address of q and r"?

Comment: The inline comments are (a) wrong, and (b) don't match the description you typed in this question (which appears to be considerably more accurate). And unrelated, print addresses with `%p`, not `%d`. The second and fourth `printf` lines should both be using `%p`.

Answer (score 2):

Your comments show that you have misunderstood a few things here.

```
printf("%d\n",*q); //getting address of q
```

You're NOT getting the address of `q`. You're dereferencing `q`, which happens to be the address of `p`. The `*` IS the dereferencing operator. If you want to print the address of `q`, then do this:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)&q); // No asterisk and you should use the %p specifier for printing pointers.
```

So, because you have made the assignment `p=&x; q=&p;` then

- `**q` is the same as `x` or `*p`
- `*q` is the same as `p`
- `q` is the the same as `&p`
- `&q` is the address of `q`

Comment: `printf("%p\n", (void*)q);` print the address stored in `q`. `printf("%p\n", (void*)&q);` prints the address of `q`.

Comment: Isn't the cast to `void *` a bit redundant since all pointers (except for function pointers) can implicitly convert to `void *` anyway?

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 This is not an implicit conversion. It has to do with that it's a variadic function.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1: There is no implicit conversion of pointers passed to `printf`. Arguments passed for a `...` in a function declaration are subject to the default argument promotions. Those do things like converting `float` to `double`, but they do not convert pointers.

Comment: @klutt I just looked it up and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867814/printfp-and-casting-to-void), so you're right, sorry about that :p

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 No worries. Have made that mistake myself. It's easy to do.