Why does changing a pointer type by casting not change the resulting pointer value?
If I cast a pointer from int32_t to int8_t, why does the pointer's value not change? I expected the resulting value to change from a 32-bit address to an 8-bit address.
When experimenting with the code below, it does not change. Why?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    int32_t * first = (int32_t *) 0xFFFFFFFF;
    int8_t * second = (int8_t *) first;

    printf("Gives: %p \n", first);
    printf("Gives: %p \n", second);

    return 0;
}


int8_t* represents a pointer (typically a 64-bit address these days) to an int8_t, not an address represented as an int8_t.

On modern computers, all pointers have the same representation, typically a 64-bit or 32-bit word. Casting between pointer types does not change this representation. Your code actually depends on this -- printf with %p is only defined for void* pointers, so when you print out the pointers, they are getting re-interpreted as void* pointers. This is technically undefined behavior (which I'd personally avoid), but is very unlikely to cause problems.

Learning exercise: Increment each pointer and print both pointer values again. Notice that the int8_t  pointer has incremented by 1 (byte), and the other int32_t pointer has incremented by 4 (bytes)... You need to appreciate that "casting" is a "source code directive" to the compiler about what executable code it produces. first is a 1 byte pointer, and second is a pointer to the first byte of a contiguous block of 4 bytes. Learn to differentiate between what is "source code" and the "machine code" the compiler outputs by following directives while translating source code.


If I cast a pointer from int32_t to int8_t, why does the pointer's value not change? I expected the resulting value to change from a 32-bit address to an 8-bit address.

Both first and second are pointers. first is pointing to an int8_t object, and second is pointing to an int32_t object.
The 8 in int8_t * denotes the number of bits in the pointed-to object, and not the pointer. The 32 in int32_t * denotes the number of bits in the pointed-to object, and not the pointer.

Side-note: %p expects void *, not uint8_t * or uint32_t *. If an argument does not match the corresponding format specifier, the behavior is undefined.

K&R Second Edition (in my bookshelf since the mid 80ties) ch 5.11 explicitly states that void* can be converted into any other pointer type and vice versa without losing information. So providing other pointer types as an argument for %p (even without explicit casting) is not UB in C.

@Halfix See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24867814/20017547

@Halfix: The fact a void * contains sufficient information to represent any pointer to an object type (K&R is not standard C; standard C does not include pointers to function types in this) does not mean it has the same format or size as other pointer types. Other pointer types could have less information. E.g., an int64_t * could have six fewer value bits than void *.

Here's another way of looking at it. In C, a union lets you declare the same memory location with different types (often useful for protocols where the format depends on the data sent). A simplified example looks like this:
union test_u {
    uint32_t first;
    uint8_t second;
};

int main(void) {
    union test_u u;
    u.first = 0xffffffff;  // Set all bits to 1
    u.second = 0;          // Sets 8 bits to 0
    printf("%x\n", u.first);  
}

The result depends on the CPU, but it will be either ffffff (top 8 bits are 0) or ffffff00 (bottom 8 bits). You could assign pointers to the union:
int main(void) {
    union test_u u;
    uint32_t *first_p = &u.first;
    uint8_t *second_p = &u.second;

    *first_p = 0xffffffff;  // Set all bits to 1
    *second_p = 0;          // Sets 8 bits to 0
    printf("%x\n", u.first);  
}

This does the same thing, only through two pointers.
Since the union only contains one value, accessed as two types, you could do the same thing with casting:
int main(void) {
    int32_t test_int;
    uint32_t *first_p = (*uint32_t)(&test_int);
    uint8_t *second_p = (*uint8_t)(&test_int);

    *first_p = 0xffffffff;  // Set all bits to 1
    *second_p = 0;          // Sets 8 bits to 0
    printf("%x\n", int32_t);  
}

Note that test_int is 32 bits, but signed. Signed or not doesn't matter because it won't be accessed directly, only the size matters. &test_int is explicitly cast to match first_p and second_p in this case, but that wasn't needed before because you could choose the union option with the matching type.

The provided code works correctly and the output is expected given the behavior of %p on your system. The key takeaway is that first and second point to the same memory address, and the printed values confirm this. The leading zeros are just a formatting detail specific to how your system represents pointer addresses.
