# How to treat a structure as a memory location and access elements separately using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, structure, ansi-c

I have a structure

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char status;
    unsigned char group_id;
    unsigned char acc_trip_level;
    unsigned char role[50];
    unsigned char standard_panic_header[50];
    unsigned char high_threat_message[50];
    unsigned char high_threat_header[50];
}cfg;

cfg test_val;
```

I'm passing this structure as an argument to a function and How can I get/access the elements of structure by memory location(in other words i want to treat this structure by memory address)

```
void foo(cfg *ptr)
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(*ptr)); //Gives size of the strcture
    printf("%p\n", (void*)ptr); //Gives the starting address of strcure
    printf("%p\n", (void*)(ptr+4));  //I want to access the 4th element/ memorylocation
}
```

Is giving me the result

```
203
0x8049780
0x8049aac
```

But it should give 8048780+4 = 8048784 right.. am I missing something

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is done in multiples of the pointee's size. Also, this is UB.

Comment: @McKay it does in both, that's how array indexing works (`a[i]` is strictly equivalent to `*(a + i)`).

Comment: Doing this is UB.  Members of a `struct` are not always contiguous, unless you explicitly set member alignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
 void foo(cfg * ptr)
 {
     printf("%zu\n", sizeof(*ptr));
     printf("%p\n", ptr);
     printf("%p\n", (void *)((char *) ptr + 4));
 }
```

And then:

```
 $ ./a.out 
 203
 0x7fffb6d04ee0
 0x7fffb6d04ee4
```

When you used `(ptr + 4)` alone, you essentially got `(ptr + 4 * sizeof(cfg))`, because pointer arithmetic works with the size of the pointee, as someone already commented.

Also, format specifier `%p` should be used for addresses.

Comment: [you should cast pointers passed to `printf` to `void*`, too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290923/when-printf-is-an-address-of-a-variable-why-use-void)

Comment: @CoffeeandCode thanks for the tip, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void foo(cfg *ptr)
{
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(cfg)); //Gives size of the strcture
    printf("%x\n",ptr); //Gives the starting address of strcure
    printf("%x\n",ptr->role);  //I want to access the 4th element/ memorylocation
}
```

If your goal is to access the internal elements of the structure by using index offsets, I recommend implementing a hash table.

Comment: The `sizeof` operator returns `size_t`. You should use `%zu` for the `printf` format.