# Dereferenced union member bytes are not the same

Tags: c, memory, unions

From the tutorial at learnc, I am experimenting with some really basic stuff on pointers and unions. In the code below I create a `struct operator` with an anonymous `union` consisting of a `float`, `double`, and `int`. Since `double` is the biggest one at eight bytes, I expect to see my `int` have eight bytes, which it does. However, they are not the same bytes as the double!

```
typedef enum {
    INTEGER = 0,
    FLOAT = 1,
    DOUBLE = 2,
} operator_type;

typedef struct operator {
    operator_type type;

    union {
        int intNum;
        double doubleNum;
        float floatNum;
    };
} operator_t;

int main() {

    operator_t op;
    op.type = FLOAT;
    op.floatNum = 3.14f;

    printf("op.intNum = %i\nop.doubleNum = %f\nop.floatNum = %f\n", op.intNum, op.doubleNum, op.floatNum);

    printf("op.intNum [%i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i]",
           &(op.intNum) + 0,
           &(op.intNum) + 1,
           &(op.intNum) + 2,
           &(op.intNum) + 3,
           &(op.intNum) + 4,
           &(op.intNum) + 5,
           &(op.intNum) + 6,
           &(op.intNum) + 7,
           &(op.intNum) + 8
           );

    printf("op.doubleNum [%i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i]",
           &(op.doubleNum) + 0,
           &(op.doubleNum) + 1,
           &(op.doubleNum) + 2,
           &(op.doubleNum) + 3,
           &(op.doubleNum) + 4,
           &(op.doubleNum) + 5,
           &(op.doubleNum) + 6,
           &(op.doubleNum) + 7,
           &(op.doubleNum) + 8
    );

    return 0;
}
```

I get the output:

```
op.intNum [-13304, -13300, -13296, -13292, -13288, -13284, -13280, -13276, -13272]
op.doubleNum [-13304, -13296, -13288, -13280, -13272, -13264, -13256, -13248, -13240]
```

Shouldn't `&(op.intNum) == &(op.doubleNum) == &(op.floatNum)` ?

Comment: What are you printing?

Comment: The int representation of each of the eight bytes stored by that union?

Comment: Are you trying to print the addresses or the values of those bytes?

Comment: Sorry, yes the address not the values.

Comment: To print a pointer you should use the format specifier `"%p"` and cast to `(void *)`, but those are going to be pointers to `int`, so you are not going to have the expected result either.

Comment: You need `%p`, not `%i`, to print the addresses. Moreover, you should cast to `void*`. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286451/how-to-print-variable-addresses-in-c).

Comment: @gsamaras, @Bob__ thanks very much, using %p and casting the dereferenced `&op` to `(void *)` made the two have the same output

Comment: BTW, you should forget that `%i` even exists, even for integers. Use `%d` for ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't `&(op.intNum)` == `&(op.doubleNum)` == `&(op.floatNum)`?

Yes, they should, and they are.

In order to print an address, use `%p` as the format specifier, and cast it to `void*`. Read more in [How to print variable addresses in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286451/how-to-print-variable-addresses-in-c)

Edit: [Why do I have to cast my memory address to (void *)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800336/why-do-i-have-to-cast-my-memory-address-to-void)

Comment: So one more quick question ... actually, casting them to `(void *)` is what made them have the same output, the output format might have been nonsense because of the `%i`, but it is interesting to me still that the `(void *)` cast is necessary.

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos About that, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867814/printfp-and-casting-to-void

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos I posted a duplicated of Bob. Pointers *can* have different representations, so they need to be casted into something generic..

Answer (score 1):

`&(op.intNum) + 1`  is the address immediately after the end of `op.intNum`.

That is, if op.intNum is at address A, and sizeof op.intNum is 4, then the expression you wrote has value A+4.

That's a consequence of how pointer arithmetic is defined.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't dereference union, for dereferencing you need to declare op as pointer.

FYI:

In your code you print

- address of int member, and sizeof(int) is 4 in your architecture, so  increment by 1 , your address will be address + sizeof(int)
- address of double member and sizeof(double) in 8,  in this case each after each increment your address will be address + 8

Hope this will help.